# Get list of strings as individual values

Tags: python, string

Given a list of strings

```
Candy = ["Snickers", "Reeses", "Twix"]
```

I want the values to be printed out individually

```
>>>Candy
>>>'Snickers', 'Reeses', 'Twix'
```

I've tried using `"'{0}'".format("', '".join(Candy))` but the problem is that this wraps the entirety of the variable in quotes and returns `"'Snickers', 'Reeses', 'Twix'"`

But I need

```
'Snickers', 'Reeses', 'Twix'
```

Comment: And simply `print(*Candy)` does not comply with what you need, because? If it is really the exact format you need, then `print("'"+"', '".join(Candy) + "'")` will do the trick..

Comment: The values are being inserted into another line of code that only takes `'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3'` so I need them all individually if possible.

Comment: If you are inputting into another function, you don't want to be outputting a comma-separated string combining the 3 items. You can use `Candy[i]` to index the list by position.

Comment: @ATCH_torn. I smell major xy here

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The only way you can do that is to have the values in a list or a tuble. You could, however, assign each value to a variable:

```
snickers, reeses, twix = Candy
```

And as per [pep-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names), please use lower case for variable names.